# How to execute cleanup code on a thread pool thread before it is reused

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, threadpool

When using the Task Parallel Library or other functions in .net that execute code in threads from the thread pool, threads are reused for different tasks that are unrelated to each other.

I have an issue that some code that is executed in a thread from the thread pool may change the environment of the thread (like thread-local culture, impersonation or similar things) that can affect other code which runs on the same thread later on.

Is there any way to register a function to be run in a thread from the thread pool before it is returned to the pool or before it is taken from the pool.

This function could then do some cleanup, resetting the thread environment to default settings.

---

To clarify: This is a huge project with lots of already existing code and several programmers working on the project. Also, different methods are used to access threadool threads, not only the TPL, but also `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` directly.

I am looking for a way to solve this at a central place without having to adapt all single instances of code running in pooled threads.

Comment: You don't need the thread pool to provide such a hook for you.  Just have your own code that you're running in the thread restore that state when you're ready to.

Comment: Just *don't* pollute the environment. If it's a big project with a lot of programmers, you *really* shouldn't pollute it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sometimes you have to, for example, you may be in a spot where you need to create a synchronization context for some code, or there may be library code you can't change that looks at some state.  Obviously any time you're changing said state you do need to clean it up; you simply don't need any "hook" to do so, you can just make the code responsible for changing the state also responsible for restoring it.

Comment: Always tidying up after changing the environment would certainly be the better approach. But I am working with a whole lot of existing code, some even in external un-managed libraries. Refactoring the existing code to add cleanup will take some time, and I am looking for a solution to solve the existing issues in the meantime.

Comment: Any chance to introduce some AOP logic? Like `PostSharp` post execute advice pointcut?

Answer (score 0):

For example, when calling the `StartNew` factory method, you can schedule multiple methods on the same task. You set up the cleanup logic after performing the work, so that after `StartNew` is complete, the thread is back to its original state. I assume it will be similar for other TPL methods.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        First();
        Second();
        Third();
    }).Wait();

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void First()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
}

static void Second()
{
    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pl-PL");
}

static void Third()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
}
```

This code will print "en-Us", but if you uncomment the line in `Second()`, it will print "pl-PL".

There is some potential for making a specialized method, for example:

```
static Task StartNewAndCleanup(Action action)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        action();
        Cleanup();
    });
}

static void Cleanup()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pl-PL");
}
```

Comment: Problem here is that every programmer must remember to add the cleanup code. This is a huge program with lots of already existing code and several programmers working on the project. Also, different methods are used to access threadool threads, not only the TPL, but also ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem directly. I am looking for a way to solve this at a central place without having to adapt all single instances of code running in pooled threads.

Comment: *Don't* pollute the task then. Pass the CultureInfo object explicitly. The compiler warns you to do that with single-threaded code.